# jquery Datepicker setdate change format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery UI datepicker on MVC2 to set my startdate picker.

When I go to the 'create' view, I want the datepicker to hold its minimal value- which is today.

But for some reason I see the date format string like this: mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM or PM.
only before the user pick a date- after the user picks a date I get the format that I want: mm/dd/yyyy in both of my datepickers- dateStart and dateEnd

and when I go to edit, I get the value from the database (date datatype) and have the same problem.
this is my code:

```
$(function () {
        var buttonImage = $(".selector").datepicker("option", "buttonImage"); // date image

        // Datepicker
        $('#DateStart').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: '/Content/calandar2.gif',
            minDate: '+0',
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate') || new Date(); // Selected date or today if none
                $('#DateEnd').datepicker('option', { minDate: min });
            }
        });

        $('#DateEnd').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: '/Content/calandar2.gif',
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            minDate: '+0'
        });
}
```

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is with the HtmlHelper and the DateTime value.

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.SomeDate) %>
```

or

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(model=>model.SomeDate) %>
```

Which by default will call `DateTime.ToString()`

If that is the case you can either convert it to be simply

```
<%
  var theValue = //something to get your date time and call .ToShortDateString()
%>
<%=Html.TextBox("DateStart", value) %>
```

If you are using templates you can also do this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%
    string value;
    if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue) 
        value = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
    else 
        value = string.Empty;
%>
<%=Html.TextBox("", value) %>
```

Comment: i opened a new EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx in the shared view and copy/paste your code, and i have to say, it worked like magic!!! thank you!!!